# White labelling Android Application without Flavours

Tags: android

I want to develop a white labelled application, but the requirement is not to use product flavours.

Is there a way to achieve white labelling without using product flavours in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert pretty much the whole app to an android library.

For new white label apps you then need to create a new android project. There you can configure things like the app name, override strings and other resources and modify the theme.
Then import your library into your app and start it's main activity.

If you make changes to your core app, you can publish them as a new library version and easily update it in all your white label apps.